# React-Redux: ¿Cómo mostrar un elemento en particular desde mi reducer?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux

Tengo muchas dudas con React-Redux. En estos momentos estoy bastante trabado con una segunda pantalla de mi proyecto. Estoy manejandome con este JSON que estoy consultando con Axios:

**RESPUESTA DEL JSON:**

```
[
conos: 
     [
     {"id": 0,…},
     {"id": 1,…},
     {"id": 2,…},
     {"id": 3,…},
     {"id": 4,…},
     {"id": 5,…},
     {"id": 6,…},
     {"id": 7,…},
    ],
date: "16/11/2020 a las 0:50:48"
]
```

Resumidamente, preciso mostrar en mi pantalla la información de cada objeto de `conos`. Es decir, un cono en particular, por ejemplo: `{"id": 0,...}`.

En mi `action creator` estoy manejando mi payload como `payload: res.conos` ya que ahí dentro está la información que necesito. Pero yo debo mostrar la información de un cono en particular cuando haga clic en un botón (creo que no hace falta mostrar eso, dado el caso edito el thread y lo muestro).

Aquí les dejo mi **action creator**:

```
export const fetchCono = (ip) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: FETCH_CONO_PENDING });
  try {
    let res = await fetchConoAPI(ip);
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_CONO_FULFILL, payload: res.conos });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_CONO_REJECT, payload: error.message });
  }
};
```

Aquí está mi **reducer**:

```
const initialState = {
  isGetting: false,
  currentCono: [],
  fetchConoErrorMessage: null,
};


export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_CONO_FULFILL:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentCono: action.payload,
        isGetting: false,
      };
    case FETCH_CONO_PENDING:
      return { ...state, isGetting: true };
    case FETCH_CONO_REJECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        isGetting: false,
        fetchConoErrorMessage: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Espero haberme explicado bien, cualquier cosa estoy atento. Muchas gracias!

Comment: No veo que tengas una lista de `conos` en Redux, solo veo un `currentCono`. Necesitarías pasarle el identificador del elemento que quieras mostrar al `reducer` a través del `payload`, y luego filtrar la lista para encontrarlo (por ejemplo con `state.conos.filter(item => item.id === payload.id)`).

Comment: Exacto, en mi payload tengo una lista de conos, en mi reducer quiero mostrar un solo cono (el que seleccioné) @Gabri podrías explicarte un poco mejor?

Comment: No entiendo por qué le pasas la lista completa en el `payload`, yo crearía una lista en el `initialState` para almacenarla y en el `payload` le mandaría únicamente en identificador del elemento que quiero recuperar.

Comment: Le paso la lista completa porque dentro de `res.conos` están los conos que necesito, pero si puede ser de otra forma, estaría buenísimo ver cómo quedaría. En mi `initialState`, `currentCono` arranca vacío, a eso te referías? Si me puedes mostrar como quedaría, me ayudarías un montonazo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que es más fácil de lo que parece.

Yo guardaría en el `state` de Redux la lista completa de conos, por ejemplo:

```
const initialState = {
    isGetting: false,
    conosList: [], // aquí la lista
    currentCono: [],
    fetchConoErrorMessage: null
}
```

Lanzaríamos una acción para guardar todos los conos en esa lista:

```
dispatch({ type: SET_CONOS, payload: res.conos })
```

Y el reductor sería algo así:

```
case SET_CONOS:
    return {
        ...state,
        conosList: payload
    }
```

Para obtener un cono de la lista a través de su identificador no es necesario ejecutar ninguna acción contra Redux, simplemente accedes al estado y lo buscas (por ejemplo, usando `useSelector`).

En tu componente harías algo tipo:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const App = (props) => {
    const conosList = useSelector(state => state.conosList)

    const getCono = (id) => {
        return conosList.filter(cono => cono.id === id)
    }

    return <button onClick={() => getCono(3)}>Obtener cono</button>
}
```

Este es un código de ejemplo, espero te sirva para tener una idea base de lo que esperas.

Comment: Me sirvió, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Ahora, tengo una duda, cómo haría para que a `getCono(id)` no tenga que ponerle el ID del cono por parámetro? Es decir, sin ponerle a mano que es el cono `"id": 3`?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a por qué puse el `3` a fuego? A la función le pasarías el identificador del cono que necesites, en el ejemplo puse `3` pero más bien sería una variable correspondiente a cada registro.